# height width according to device size - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div element like below

```
<!--CONTENT WRAPPER -->
<div class="content-wrapper about-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <p>Dear friends,</p>
                <br>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.! </p>
                <br>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page. </p>
                <br>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page. </p>
                <br>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page. Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.Lorem Ipsum is just a dummy text for a web page.</p>
                <br>
                <p>I wish you a good experience and a super day ahead! </p>
                <br>
                <p>Yours sincerely,</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--CONTENT WRAPPER -->
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/h4pce7tL/1/) somewhat similar fiddle.
I am not able to set the height and width of the pages according to the mobile/tablet's size?

I have a number of pages where there are problems like these. For eg. On iPad I see a white space below when the content is less on the page.

For example, this page has less content but If I scroll I see empty unused space, It shouldn't be the case.

```
<div class="content-wrapper contact-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
                        <br>
                        <p>test.comm </p>
                        <p>TEST PVT LTD</p>
                        <p>Mumbai 400012, India.</p>
                        <p>Contact No. :   + 91 21455487 </p>
                        <p>[Mon-Sat, 9:30 AM - 5:30 PM IST]</p>
                        <p>Toll Free No.   :   145414 </p>
                        <p>[Toll free while calling from within India]</p>
                        <p>Email ID    :   abc@pqr.com</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

It's CSS is here:

```
.contact-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 380px;
    top:134px;
}
.contact-wrapper p {color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

What could be the best solution for it?

Media queries?

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you include bootstrap in your code both JS and CSS. Also did you add this line in your header:`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and regarding height for all the devices it needs to be given in `%` it is not done in bootstrap
`

Comment: `    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Yes have this and I am using CDN properly

Comment: have you tried seting the height of the element to 100vh?

Comment: not really @madalinivascu

Comment: How the vh would work @madalinivascu. Should I give the body 100vh or the external class?

Comment: With the help of `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and `media queries` you can adjust the width of your web page. But the height will be adjust according to content. I think you should not go for the height, You should just concentrate on adjusting width of the web page.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, the code is working as expected, what do you want to change? height: 100%; will use 100% of the height available, its how it works, if the parent is 100px height, 100% is 100px!

Comment: @AramilRey I want the height and width to work according to the device size. 

It is not happening at the moment. I have fixed header and footer and to achieve that I have used certain padding and top properties to get it working. Now, as per devices, it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to get the contact-wrapper to fill the whole page? If so, you need to set

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

in order to get full height covered. Otherwise the contact-wrappers height is just as much as it has content.

Here's a modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4pce7tL/2/

Comment: It looks fine in the fiddle but not working for me on my project.

Comment: this causes whole lot of problem where for some reason, I can't scroll after certain part on the webpage.

Comment: How about if you change the height to min-height?

Comment: of the body? or the element?

Comment: html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

Comment: nope, doesn't work.. What should be height for the element?

Comment: If you wish it to be full width, then 100%. But I would put height:auto or wouldn't define it at all on mobile because the window width can vary so much depending on the device and putting height:auto lets it scale automatically. Like it is on your fiddle. I don't actually know what you're asking right now because your latest fiddle is working like you originally wished?

Answer (score 0):

For  small screen devices, you better use `col-sm-12`. And to optimize height, try to media query text size. Do not worry much about height. Because height is not of much importance, while styling responsive layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for mobile devices we control WIDTH and let the device scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the fixed padding-bottom: 380px and top:134px. 
Try this

```
  padding-bottom: auto;
  top: auto;
```

Comment: I need that `padding-bottom` and `top`.

So can't have it as auto